# Formulario Java

Tags: java

Estoy intentando realizar *un formulario con NetBeans 8.2*, al utilizar los métodos "this.setLocationRelativeTo();" y "this.getContentPane().setBackground();" *me genera un error*. El formulario lo cree desde el asistente gráfico de NetBeans. *Estoy dentro de "Source"*. Estoy editando el constructor:

```
public sistema(){
    initComponents();
    
    //Aparezca al centro de la pantalla
    this.setLocationRelativeTo();
    //Cambiar fondo de pantalla.
    this.getContentPane().setBackground();
```

}

Alguien sabe cómo puedo solucionarlo. *Netbeans, me sugiere crear esos métodos*, pero se supone que los *hereda de swing.Jpanel*.

Comment: Para centrar es ``setLocationRelativeTo(null)`` y el otro ``setBackground(Color.RED)`` <- por ejemplo, podes mirar la documentación de Java, y si hereda de JPanel, creo que no existe ``getContentPane()`` este es del JFrame

Comment: "Para centrar es setLocationRelativeTo(null)" Tienes razón, pero no me funciona. ¿Cuál será el error? ¿Debo importar algo adicional?

Comment: Si la clase Sistema extiende de JPanel, el metodo ``setLocationRelativeTo(null)`` No existe en JPanel, este de debe aplicar al JFrame

Comment: ¿Cómo una interfaz? ¿Cuál sería la declaración, para hacerlo?

Comment: Ya lo solucione, ¡gracias por hacerme caer en cuenta! Lo tenia como: public class sistema extends javax.swing.JPanel y lo cambie a sistema extends javax.swing.JFrame. Ya funciona.  ¿Genera algún problema? Debido a que el código lo genero el asistente grafico.

Comment: No tengo idea porque el generador de GUI te dejaría agregar propiedades en un JFrame cuando extendías de JPanel, pero probablemente en vez de crear un componente JFrame agregaste para crear un componente JPanel y el código autogenero un ``extends JPanel``, y las otras propiedades las hallas escrito a mano (setLoca... y el getConte...), lo que genero un error por ser de otro componente.

Comment: Tienes razón. Gracias por la ayuda. ¡En serio me sirvió mucho! ;)